# How to set the default value "on" in input tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html-input

I used html input tag type checkbox in html. Then i get the value attribute of input tag in javascript, it return "on" value. But i didn't write value attribute. How to set the default value "on"?

Answer (score -1):

The default value, when you don't provide a `value` attribute, is determined by the browser, as required by [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set), which says:

> Otherwise, if the field element is an input element whose type attribute is in the Checkbox state or the Radio Button state, then run these further nested substeps:
>
> If the field element has a value attribute specified, then let value be the value of that attribute; otherwise, let value be the string "on".

If you want to change it, use a `value` attribute. You can't change it globally.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You're looking to add `checked` at the end of your checkbox field. See this link for more information.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp